# Execution time for map partition in spark using accumulator

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have been trying to find the execution time for the map partition to happen

```
    long start=System.nanoTime();
    MapPartitionsFunction<Row, Row> mapPartitionsFunction = new MapPartitionsFunction<Row, Row>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<Row> call(final Iterator<Row> iterator) throws Exception {
            return lookUpDataFrame(iterator);
        }
    };

    df = dataset.mapPartitions(mapPartitionsFunction, RowEncoder.apply(lookUpSchema));
    long end=System.nanoTime();
    long timeTaken=(end-start)/1000000000;
```

The action is in other class, which I don't have control over.

I know that this execution takes 100 seconds, whereas the above code gave me 1 seconds as answer. I did some search and found that this is due to lazy execution of spark. Now, I tried using an accumulator for this purpose and passed it in the partition function.

```
LongAccumulator longAccumulator=spark.sparkContext().longAccumulator();
MapPartitionsFunction<Row, Row> mapPartitionsFunction = new MapPartitionsFunction<Row, Row>() {
    @Override
    public Iterator<Row> call(final Iterator<Row> iterator) throws Exception {
        return lookUpDataFrame(iterator,longAccumulator);
    }
};
```

and made the lookup method like this:-

```
public static Iterator<Row> lookUpDataFrame(Iterator<Row> partition, LongAccumulator longAccumulator){
    long start=System.nanoTime();
    //my logic.....
    long end=System.nanoTime();
    longAccumulator.add((end-start)/1000000000);
    //rest of code
}
```

I thought I will divide the accumulator value by number of executors(which is 36 in my case), but that value is coming like 18 seconds, which is not close to what I expect.

I tried another apporach where I forced an action just after the partition like this

```
long start=System.nanoTime();
MapPartitionsFunction<Row, Row> mapPartitionsFunction = new MapPartitionsFunction<Row, Row>() {
    @Override
    public Iterator<Row> call(final Iterator<Row> iterator) throws Exception {
        return lookUpDataFrame(iterator);
    }
};

df = dataset.mapPartitions(mapPartitionsFunction, RowEncoder.apply(lookUpSchema));
df=df.persist();
long count=df.count();
long end=System.nanoTime();
long timeTaken=(end-start)/1000000000;
```

But this was giving performance and memory issues due to count and persist being used. However, it gave the correct answer.

What should I do? I have already searched in other answers but haven't been able to tackle the issue.

Comment: What is you remove `persist` and keep the `count` that should still force the execution?

Comment: It still forces the execution but there is one action called at end of application also. So, if I don't use persist, the 'df' needs to be evaulated again. I was getting double time when I did that. Also, count is giving perfomance issues, so I can't use it anyways.

Comment: I see, yes, if you have multiple actions then using `persist` would be preferable. If something simple as `count` is giving performance issues, then it sounds like your resources are not enough/not optimally configured. As for your question, the last approach should be best (seeing as the result is correct), the problems should be a separate issue.

Comment: This code is regarding a lookups on table, so it's being called many times inside the spark job(with different queries). On smaller scales, it's working good but on when were doing many lookups, it's giving issues.